# Work-item distribution between multiple docker images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I am new to docker world and looking for solution to below problem.

I have an existing solution where we have multiple work items in database table. There is windows service running on multiple windows servers which makes calls to this table to get work items and starts working on it.

The work items are distributed equally between the servers. So when each server makes call to the DB it passes it’s unique server id to get its work items.In this solution we have fixed servers where application is running and I am able to distribute the work items equally.

I am trying to migrate this application to docker containers. I don’t know how I can handle the distribution between multiple images of the application.

Comment: Consider each instance of the image like you would the servers today. If you need a unique id for each container, you can set one using an environment variable or you can use the hostname (which will be the same as the container id).

Comment: A dedicated job queue (for example, RabbitMQ) could be an appropriate solution here too.  What are you doing today; what happens when you try to run it in Docker or Kubernetes; can you provide any sample code?

Comment: What do you think about implementing message queue in Kubernetes ?
You can find useful articles [here](https://devops.com/implementing-message-queue-in-kubernetes/) and [here](https://dzone.com/articles/microservice-messaging-in-kubernetes).

Comment: Hello - No. There is no update yet. I am not sure how can I use message queues in Kubernates as suggested by @matt_j